# GDB not showing symbols of stripped core files even if a non-stripped version is given

Tags: c++11, gdb, coredump

I built the program by classic configure, make, make install.  Some months after, the program crashed.  I still have the build directory where both the source and the non-stripped executable reside.  From there, I call gdb like so:

```
530-north:courier$ gdb -q --core /tmp/core_epoch\=1667475742_pid\=23653_file\=\!usr\!local\!libexec\!courier\!courierd courierd
Reading symbols from courierd...
[New LWP 23653]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `/usr/local/libexec/courier/courierd'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0000561e841e5afd in msgq::completed(drvinfo&, unsigned long) ()
(gdb) info args
No symbol table info available.
```

With `bt` I can see a long sequence of calls between two functions:

```
#0  0x0000561e841e5afd in msgq::completed(drvinfo&, unsigned long) ()
#1  0x0000561e841e609a in msgq::startdelivery(drvinfo*, delinfo*) ()
#2  0x0000561e841e5bd8 in msgq::completed(drvinfo&, unsigned long) ()
#3  0x0000561e841e609a in msgq::startdelivery(drvinfo*, delinfo*) ()
#4  0x0000561e841e5bd8 in msgq::completed(drvinfo&, unsigned long) ()
...
#204 0x0000561e841e5a17 in msgq::completed(drvinfo&, unsigned long) ()
#205 0x0000561e841e609a in msgq::startdelivery(drvinfo*, delinfo*) ()
#206 0x0000561e841e5a17 in msgq::completed(drvinfo&, unsigned long) ()
#207 0x0000561e841e70fe in courierbmain() ()
#208 0x0000561e841dd030 in main ()
```

Every couple of calls advances the stack by 0x110, for a total of ~27Kb, which is much less of the running processes' allocated 132Kb of stack, so it's not stack overflow.  SIGSEGV could be from a null pointer or whatever.  Why doesn't gdb point at it?  This is GNU gdb (Debian 10.1-1.7) 10.1.90.20210103-git, BTW.

If I omit the last argument to gdb, `bt` doesn't show the function names.  Did I screw up compilation? On config.log I see I had `'CFLAGS= -march=nocona -O2 -g' 'LDFLAGS= -march=nocona -O2' 'CXXFLAGS= -march=nocona -O2 -std=c++11'`.  The source file is C++.  Perhaps I missed some `-g`s?  Yet, *some* symbols are there...

Comment: Your `CXXFLAGS` doesn't include `-g`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesn't gdb point at it?

Because you haven't compiled your program with appropriate debug info.

You'll have to debug this crash at the assembly level. Start with `disasemble $pc` and `info registers`.

> The source file is C++. Perhaps I missed some -gs?

Yes: your `CXXFLAGS` don't have `-g`.

> Yet, some symbols are there...

On UNIX systems (unlike Windows), function names (symbols) are present (by default) even without `-g`. There is no contradiction here.

**Update:**

> However, if I don't pass the non-stripped file as argument, the function names are not displayed.

Yes: `strip` removes the symbols *and* debug info.

You can observe this by using a trivial test:

```
// t.cc
#include <cstdlib>

struct S {
  void fn() { abort(); }
};

int main()
{
  S().fn();
}
```

First let's see how it works when the binary is built correctly for debugging:

```
g++ -g t.cc -o a.out && strip ./a.out -o a.out.stripped &&
./a.out.stripped; gdb -q --batch -ex where ./a.out core
Aborted (core dumped)
...
warning: core file may not match specified executable file.
[New LWP 476070]
Core was generated by `./a.out.stripped'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  __pthread_kill_implementation (threadid=<optimized out>, signo=6, no_tid=no_tid@entry=0) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:44
44      ./nptl/pthread_kill.c: No such file or directory.
#0  __pthread_kill_implementation (threadid=<optimized out>, signo=6, no_tid=no_tid@entry=0) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:44
#1  0x00007f12444895df in __pthread_kill_internal (signo=<optimized out>, threadid=<optimized out>) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:89
#2  __GI___pthread_kill (threadid=<optimized out>, signo=<optimized out>) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:89
#3  0x00007f12445f5e70 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007f1244428469 in __GI_abort () at ./stdlib/abort.c:79
#5  0x000055de28a24165 in S::fn (this=0x7ffcd0d1d80f) at t.cc:4
#6  0x000055de28a2414d in main () at t.cc:9
```

Note presence of file/line info and function names. If we use the stripped version, neither is present:

```
ore was generated by `./a.out.stripped'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  __pthread_kill_implementation (threadid=<optimized out>, signo=6, no_tid=no_tid@entry=0) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:44
44      ./nptl/pthread_kill.c: No such file or directory.
#0  __pthread_kill_implementation (threadid=<optimized out>, signo=6, no_tid=no_tid@entry=0) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:44
#1  0x00007f12444895df in __pthread_kill_internal (signo=<optimized out>, threadid=<optimized out>) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:89
#2  __GI___pthread_kill (threadid=<optimized out>, signo=<optimized out>) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:89
#3  0x00007f12445f5e70 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007f1244428469 in __GI_abort () at ./stdlib/abort.c:79
#5  0x000055de28a24165 in ?? ()
#6  0x000055de28a2414d in ?? ()
#7  0x00007f124442920a in __libc_start_call_main (main=main@entry=0x55de28a24139, argc=argc@entry=1, argv=argv@entry=0x7ffcd0d1d928) at ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58
#8  0x00007f12444292bc in __libc_start_main_impl (main=0x55de28a24139, argc=1, argv=0x7ffcd0d1d928, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7ffcd0d1d918) at ../csu/libc-start.c:389
#9  0x000055de28a24071 in ?? ()
```

Now let's repeat with *incorrectly* built binary (which is what you have):

```
g++ t.cc -o b.out && strip ./b.out -o b.out.stripped &&
./b.out.stripped; gdb -q --batch -ex where ./b.out core
Aborted (core dumped)
...
warning: core file may not match specified executable file.
[New LWP 478614]
Core was generated by `./b.out.stripped'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  __pthread_kill_implementation (threadid=<optimized out>, signo=6, no_tid=no_tid@entry=0) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:44
44      ./nptl/pthread_kill.c: No such file or directory.
#0  __pthread_kill_implementation (threadid=<optimized out>, signo=6, no_tid=no_tid@entry=0) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:44
#1  0x00007f21a0a895df in __pthread_kill_internal (signo=<optimized out>, threadid=<optimized out>) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:89
#2  __GI___pthread_kill (threadid=<optimized out>, signo=<optimized out>) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:89
#3  0x00007f21a0bf5e70 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007f21a0a28469 in __GI_abort () at ./stdlib/abort.c:79
#5  0x000056049b052165 in S::fn() ()
#6  0x000056049b05214d in main ()
```

Notice presence of function names (`S::fn()`, `main`) but *lack* of file/line/argument info. This matches your observed result.

If you try again with `b.out.stripped`, you'll get the same result as you had from previous run with `a.out.stripped`:

```
Core was generated by `./b.out.stripped'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  __pthread_kill_implementation (threadid=<optimized out>, signo=6, no_tid=no_tid@entry=0) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:44
44      ./nptl/pthread_kill.c: No such file or directory.
#0  __pthread_kill_implementation (threadid=<optimized out>, signo=6, no_tid=no_tid@entry=0) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:44
#1  0x00007f21a0a895df in __pthread_kill_internal (signo=<optimized out>, threadid=<optimized out>) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:89
#2  __GI___pthread_kill (threadid=<optimized out>, signo=<optimized out>) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:89
#3  0x00007f21a0bf5e70 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007f21a0a28469 in __GI_abort () at ./stdlib/abort.c:79
#5  0x000056049b052165 in ?? ()
#6  0x000056049b05214d in ?? ()
#7  0x00007f21a0a2920a in __libc_start_call_main (main=main@entry=0x56049b052139, argc=argc@entry=1, argv=argv@entry=0x7fff3554bc78) at ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58
#8  0x00007f21a0a292bc in __libc_start_main_impl (main=0x56049b052139, argc=1, argv=0x7fff3554bc78, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fff3554bc68) at ../csu/libc-start.c:389
#9  0x000056049b052071 in ?? ()
```

> In addition, readelf --debug-dump=info courierd shows lots of Version 4 stuff.

Yes, if you run `readelf --debug-dump b.out`, you *could* observe a lot of DWARF4 stuff coming from  `crt0.o`, `crtbegin.o`, etc (depending on how your GCC and GLIBC were built).

If you have `.c` files linked in, these will also have DWARF4 debug info, since your `CFLAGS` *do* include `-g`.

But none of the DWARF4 stuff will be coming from wherever `msgq::completed` is defined.

Comment: However, if I don't pass the non-stripped file as argument, the function names are not displayed.  In addition, `readelf --debug-dump=info courierd` shows lots of Version 4 stuff.

Comment: @Ale I've updated the answer -- there is _still_ no contradiction.

Comment: You're right.  I recompiled with added -g flags and it shows full debug info.  Unfortunately, gcc changed so pointers to the code were not reliable any more.  Variable, however, could be examined.

Comment: @EmployedRussian Any reason for the 'core file may not match specified executable file' message that pops in and out of your examples? Does stripping/re-adding debug symbols cause that?